# Are `armeabi-v7a` and `armeabi` the only two arm options to put in Application.mk for an Android app?

Tags: android, cpu-architecture

If not, what other options are there for the arm architectures in the Application.mk file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two additional options are `x86` and `mips`. I believe those 4 are the only options.

Comment: Also mips. All of this is listed in the APPLICATION-MK.html file in the docs directory.

Comment: @MorrisonChang Yea, I noticed that in the ndk introduction page, but I'm not sure what the option exactly is, is it just `mips`?

Comment: @MorrisonChang I found it, it is in fact just `mips`, updated my post to reflect that.

Comment: As of NDK r10, there is now armeabi,armeabi-v7a,x86,mips,arm64-v8a,x86_64,mips64, but "all32" "all64" or just "all" can alternatively be used, which should future proof your build script to include future architectures.